# Why does the foreach statement with the function expression work when it is not called?

Tags: javascript, foreach

I don't know why 'forEach statement' works even though i didn't call.

```
<script>

    const data = [1, 2, 3]

    const makeTree = data.forEach((el) => {
        console.log("hi")
    })
    
</script>
```

As you can see, I never call makeTree function. But when I run the code, I can see three hi in my console. Someone tell me why does this happen.

Comment: `makeTree` is not a function, it's `undefined`. You are calling `forEach` and assign its return value (`undefined`) to `makeTree`. Calling `forEach` will call the passed callback for every element in the array. Usually one doesn't use `forEach`'s return value, you'd just write `data.forEach((el) => { console.log("hi") })`

Comment: What they said, If you want it to be a function do const makeTree = (input) =>{ return input.forEach((el) => {
        console.log("hi")
    })}

Comment: Do you mean to use `.map()` instead of `.forEach()`?

Answer (score 1):

> As you can see, I never call makeTree function

`makeTree` isn't a function.

You are assigning it the return value of immediately calling `data.forEach()`.

If you want it to be a function then you need to explicitly write it as a function using either a function declaration, function expression, or arrow function.

```
function makeTree() {
    data.forEach((el) => {
        console.log("hi")
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its becouse it is a callback function similar to this:

```js
function foreackExplained(calback){
  
  calback('hollo')
}
foreackExplained( (val)=> console.log(`${val} world`) )
```

Answer (score 0):

`makeTree` as variable receive a value from right expressions, but right expressions is function call

Maybe you can read this
https://javascript.info/function-expressions

Answer (score -2):

forEach is an array function so if you are even write like this

```
array.forEach((el) => {console.log("hay")})
```

it's going to execute

in your case you are assigning a value to `maketree` but there's no need if you only want to print you can do it directly

```
    data.forEach((el) => {
    console.log("hi")
})
```

like this

if you want to restrict your forEach you can write it in some kind of if condition then it will be only executed when the condition was right

```
if(false){
data.foreach((el) => {
console.log("hellow");
}
}
```

or you can write a separate function for that and call that function when you need

**conclusion:**
forEach itself a function(Array function) so when you wright it's going to execute

**Have a good day......**

Comment: wall i can't understand what i say wrong but , good day any way